# Why must the error term in the definition of differentiability not only go to zero, but to become negligible compared to x-a

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

This question is related but ultimately does not answer my questions: [Why does the error term tend to zero faster than the difference?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1893228/why-does-the-error-term-tend-to-zero-faster-than-the-difference)

My real analysis lecturer gave this definition of differentiability:

> A function *f* is differentiable at $x=a$ if  $f(x) = f(a) + L(x-a)
>  + \eta$ , where L is independent of x and $\frac{\eta }{(x-a)}\rightarrow 0$ as $ x \rightarrow a$.

His text later says that $\eta$ cannot merely vanish but must also become negligibly small compared to $(x-a)$. What would be wrong with the definition of differentiability if this were not the case and it was suffice for $\eta$ to merely vanish? We previously were taught the concept of uniform convergence, is this related to that concept?

Comment: The general idea is that $L$ captures all the linear bits near $a$ and $\eta$ is a higher order error term. If the additional condition did not hold, the error would be of the same order as the derivative, and the derivative would not then do the job.

Comment: You could take $\eta\equiv 0$. Would differentiability make any sense then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\eta(x) = f(x)-f(a) + L(x-a)$, you have, if $f$ is continuous,

$$\lim_{x\to a} \eta(x) = \lim_{x\to a} (f(x)-f(a) + L(x-a)) = f(a)-f(a)+L(a-a)=0$$

which means that just demanding that $\eta$ vanishes would mean that **any** continuous function is differential at all points, and all real numbers $L$ are its derivative.

---

Adding the additional demand that $\frac{\eta}{x-a}\to 0$ insures that

1. $L$ might not always exist, so that differentiable functions are "more" than just continuous
2. $L$ is always unique, and it can thus be called the *derivative* or *differential* of the function.

Answer (score 0):

If $\eta=\eta(x)$ went merely to $0$ then the line
$$f(x)=f(a)+L(x-a)+\eta(x)\qquad(x\to a)$$
would be devoid of any real content. In particular you could replace $L$ by any number you please and redefine $\eta(x)$ accordingly.

Comment: ... as long as $f$ is continuous.